# Matplotlib: Labels on projection plot grid lines similar to clabel()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, astropy

I'm doing a bunch of work with various spherical projection plots using the Astropy WCS package, and have run into some frustrations concerning grid lines. As grid lines do not always intersect with the image bounding box or multiple intersect at the same place, they can go unlabeled or have their labels rendered illegible. I would like to be able to insert grid line labels in each line, much akin to the [matplotlib.pyplot.clabel()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.clabel.html?highlight=matplotlib%20axes%20axes%20clabel#matplotlib.axes.Axes.clabel) function applied to contour plots, as in this [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html). I can't embed the image as I am a new user; my apologies.

I know I can place labels using text(), figtext(), or annotate(), but since clabel() works I figure the functionality already exists, even if it hasn't been applied to grid lines. Projection plotting aside, does anyone know a way that in-line grid line labels akin to clabel() can be applied to grid lines on a plain rectangular plot?

Comment: `clabel(cs, **kwargs)`
adds labels to line contours in `cs`, where `cs` is a ContourSet object returned by `contour`. Hence you have two options: **(a)** Use a contour plot to draw the gridlines and then use clabel to label the lines **(b)** use normal gridlines and write your custom function to label them. Which one do you want help with?

Comment: btw, new users are allowed to post images, those will then appear as links instead of inline.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I couldn't include more than two links, or I would have included a couple of images. I hadn't thought about option **(a)**; I like the idea, but feel like it would be difficult to implement in such a way as to work for many different plots without a gratuitous amount of tuning. Thus I'd like to go with **(b)**; I'm hoping to find some clever way of copying the functionality from clabel() and not writing a custom gridline labeling function from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To annotate the gridlines, you may use the positions of the major ticks (as those are the positions at which the gridlines are created).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10)
y = np.sin(x)*10

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.grid()

for xi in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklocs():
    ax.text(xi,0.8, "{:.2f}".format(xi), clip_on=True, ha="center",
            transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), rotation=90,
            bbox={'facecolor':'w', 'pad':1, "edgecolor":"None"})
for yi in ax.yaxis.get_majorticklocs():
    ax.text(0.86,yi, "{:.2f}".format(yi), clip_on=True, va="center",
            transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(), 
            bbox={'facecolor':'w', 'pad':1, "edgecolor":"None"})

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that helps significantly! It's not quite optimal, as much has to be hard-coded for each plot (to avoid covering up data as much as possible, etc), but it's a step in the right direction. I feel like a bunch of code could be pulled from clabel() and applied to grid lines as opposed to contour lines, but I'm not proficient enough with matplotlib to know how to do that.

Comment: You can always make things more complicated than they need to be. The [`ContourLabeler` code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/e66b5d86743e11323d2bbc1b6eb2117d2ef535a3/lib/matplotlib/contour.py#L57) is 500 lines long and intended to be used with `ContourSet`s. In order to use it, the grid lines would need to be a `ContourSet` as well. But there is essentially no gain from that compared to the 4 lines long code from the above answer.